# click all "see more"s of posts in fb

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, node.js, console

I have a page with lots of posts in FB.
I want to copy all post's text in a txt file.
what should I do ?
is there any shortcut way ?
I scroll down untill all posts loaded and press `ctrl + a` and `ctrl + c` then paste in txt file, but some posts not copied completely, they copied till "See More".

how can I click all see mores in page ?

I tried this in Console :

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  document.getElementsByclassName('see_more_link').click();
});
```

but it doesn't worked.

any Idea to solve problem ??

( Im sorry if my enlish writing is too weak :(( )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to take a look at this Link: https://www.facebook.com/apps/site_scraping_tos_terms.php

Scraping is not allowed. If you want to get data from Facebook, you should use the API: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/.

For getting the feed of a Facebook Page with the API, take a look at this thread: [Facebook PHP SDK 3.0 - How to get my page wall posts at any time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6444802/facebook-php-sdk-3-0-how-to-get-my-page-wall-posts-at-any-time)

Comment: you mean isn't there any way to get Facebook data without The Graph Api ?? @luschn

Comment: that would be scraping, which is not allowed according to the terms.

Comment: would you plz give me an example for collect all posts from this page : facebook.com/eterafate.ahmaghaneh.shoma

Comment: see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6444802/facebook-php-sdk-3-0-how-to-get-my-page-wall-posts-at-any-time

Answer (score 0):

I came here looking how to do it, can't find how. So I made it for myself.

**This function is for running the loop in order** (Thanks to Ivo Wetzel for his answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4288992/3281648)):

```
function asyncLoop(iterations, func, callback) {
  var index = 0;
  var done = false;
  var loop = {
    next: function() {
      if (done) {
        return;
      }
      if (index < iterations) {
        index++;
        func(loop);
      } else {
        done = true;
        callback();
      }
    },
    iteration: function() {
      return index - 1;
    },
    break: function() {
      done = true;
      callback();
    }
  };
  loop.next();
  return loop;
}
```

**This other is for emulate click in the links** (can't remember where I see it):

```
function hacerClic(obj, callback) {
  var evt = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
  evt.initMouseEvent("click", true, true, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
  var canceled = !obj.dispatchEvent(evt);
  callback();
}
```

Last, we have two runs for *asyncLoop*, one for **expand the answers**:

```
var verRespuestas = document.getElementsByClassName("UFIReplySocialSentenceLinkText");
var i = 0;
asyncLoop(verRespuestas.length, function(loop) {
  hacerClic(verRespuestas[i], function(result) {
    loop.next();
    i++;
  })
}, function() {});
```

And other for **expand the 'see more'**:

```
var verMas = document.getElementsByClassName("_5v47");
var j = 0;
asyncLoop(verMas.length, function(loop) {
  hacerClic(verMas[j], function(result) {
    loop.next();
    j++;
  })
}, function() {});
```

**NOTE:** If the 'see more' loop gives error is probably because DOM isn't fully loeaded yet.